# What's going on here? Returning a value from inside a scope?

Tags: c, gcc

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    x = ({ int y=42; y; }); // What?
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

This prints 42. But I must say that I don't understand it. How does the value of `y` get assigned to `x`? This is something I have never seen in C before.

I tried to remove the parenthesis, but then I got this:

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
    6 |     x = { int y=42; y; };
      |
```

Could someone please explain what's going on here?

Comment: Isn't that some weird gnu extension?

Comment: I hope they would standardize it... :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm not sure I would want that standardized

Comment: @klutt it is very useful in making macros that are side-effect safe, together with typeof/decltype, which I remember Gustedt advocating for C20

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ah, ok. Well, I'm not a big fan of macros. ;)

Comment: @klutt then you'll love C++ templates I guess.

Answer (score 3):

After some tinkering, I made the conclusion that it is a compiler extension, because when I compiled with `-pedantic` I got this:

```
warning: ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions [-Wpedantic]
    6 |     x = ({ int y=42; y; });
      |         ^
```

Comment: This is an expression discussed in an article like : http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/c_preprocessor.html#6._Eviter_les_expressions_en_param%E8tres

Comment: You can see it in action in the Linux kernel: [The Magical container_of() Macro](https://radek.io/2012/11/10/magical-container_of-macro/)